# Flip transition takes time

Tags: iphone

I am using the example from TheElements sample code provided with the iPhone SDK to achieve flip transition between 2 views. The transition from the 1st view to the second is not as responsive as the one from second to first. I am not sure why this is happening. The transition does happen but takes almost double the time it should.

I tired comparing my code with the one in TheElements and don't see much difference in the transition portion. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be any number of things, but I suggest you start with your `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear`: methods as well as `viewWillDisappear`: and `viewDidDisappear:`.

You're most likely doing something rather processor intensive that's causing the slowdown.

Comment: Thanks. I am streaming an audio file in this class. But then if it does slow down an animation, that should happen for both left-to-right and right-to-left. How come only one of the animations is slow?